# System.out.println("Sklep:"+sklep1+sklep2); how to view

Tags: java

I have some problem with my code when I run this code:

```
Sklep{
    private static double ch; //cena hurtowa
    private static double cd; // cena detaliczna
    private int zilosc; 
    private int silosc;
    private int nr;

    static void setCenaHurtowa(double nch){ ch = nch; }
    static void setCenaDetaliczna(double ncd){ cd = ncd;}
    {licznik++;}
    public Sklep(){
        zilosc = 0;
        silosc = 0;
        nr=licznik;
    }

    void kupno(int nzilosc){
        zilosc = nzilosc;
    }

    void sprzedaz(int nsilosc){
        silosc = nsilosc;
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args){
    Sklep.setCenaHurtowa(1.5);
    Sklep.setCenaDetaliczna(3);
    Sklep sklep1 = new Sklep();
    Sklep sklep2 = new Sklep();
    Sklep sklep3 = new Sklep();
    sklep1.kupno(100);
    sklep2.kupno(200);
    sklep3.kupno(300);
    System.out.println("Sklep:"+sklep1+sklep2);                   
}
```

Console give me:

> Sklep:zad_1$Sklep@35a8767zad_1$Sklep@2c6f7ce9

How can I get something like this:

> Sklep nr 1 aktualny stan jabłek 100.0 kg
>
> Sklep nr 2 aktualny stan jabłek 200.0 kg

Or where I can find an answer?

Comment: We don't understand Czech or Polish, please use English (Shop, in your case).

Comment: @MouseEvent we understand code though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Override toString()` method in your **Sklep class**. By default, it call's `Object.toString()`.

Something like:

```
 public class Sklep{


  public String toString(){
     return "put whatever you wanna return from toString here";
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
  Sklep sk = new Sklep();
  //rest of your code
  System.out.println(sk);

   }

 }
```